# ¿Cómo ejecutar código C# en monodevelop, error de compilacion?

Tags: c#, mono

Buenas programando en linux, `c#` en monodevelop, de repente mi IDE a dejado de compilar con este mensaje de error. he buscado por la web y en los bugs de monodevelop oficial y nada.

> Done building project "/home/dan5erv3r/Documentos/archivos /Programs01_1c#/Programs01_1/CiclosRepetitivos/CiclosRepetitivos/CiclosRepetitivos.csproj".

[image: No ejecuta el archivo, cero errores de codigo. Arriba se puede ver el error]

[EDIT] El error viene en la foto, en la linea superior del IDE, "No se puede ejecutar", es un build and run.

```
using System;
namespace CiclosRepetitivos
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        int i=0,n=10;
        while (i<=n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("10 primeros numeros enteros"+1);
            i++
            if (i%2==1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Numeros impares"+i);
                i++; //Aumenta dos veces por iteración
            }   
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadKey(); //Fuera de Main
```

Comment: Entiendo por el mensaje que el building se ha completado. ¿Podrías compartir el código que intentas compilar, por si se puede reproducir el error?

Comment: ¿Puede ser que simplemente lo estés compilando en vez de ejecutando?

Comment: Al momento de compilar esta todo correcto sin ningun error, el problema esta en que como dices no ejecuta el programa... el programa es mandar a imprimir numeros impares en un ciclo for...